# Javascript lists and arrays indexing

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, loops

Given an array X, write a program that will remove all negative numbers and replace them with a 0. For example, for array X = [2,-1,4,-3] the output of your program should be [2,0,4,0].

So I searched entire Google, but didn't found any good answers.

This is my code by far:

```
var x = [2, -1, 4, -3]

for(index in x){
    if (index < 0){
    console.log('Yra minusas')
 }
}
```

Comment: "So I searched entire Google, but didn't found any good answers" -- perhaps because the *point* is to write your own good answer?

Comment: Question is: How to check every number in array so Google comes and shows me every() function :/

Comment: @Emilis you do have the loop body already. That is already more than half the work you needed to do. The only piece needed was to replace the `console.log` with the code to change the value.

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does the trick:

```js
var x = [2, -1, 4, -3];
console.log(x.map(item => item > 0 ? item : 0));

// Or even shorter, as suggested in comments:
console.log(x.map(item => Math.max(item, 0)));
```

Comment: For this case, I'd personally `Math.max(item, 0)` than a ternary. The code is working with numbers and a ternary seems overly verbose when the code means "if number is more than X return number otherwise return X". You are really only looking at X or a higher value, hence why `max` makes it less verbose in meaning and in terms of code. As a side-benefit (for me) `Math.max` sounds a bit like Mad Max and it gives me a small chuckle. Hey, I get my laughs where I can.

Answer (score 1):

The [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement iterates over all *non-Symbol*, *enumerable properties* of an object but the order of iteration is not guaranteed in any specific order. Thus you should avoid [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for the iteration of an array.

You can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which will allow you to create a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
var x = [2, -1, 4, -3]
x = x.map( i => {
  if(i < 0) i = 0;
  return i;
});

console.log(x)
```

**OR:** With [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var x = [2, -1, 4, -3]
x.forEach((item, i) => {
  if(item < 0)
    x[i] = 0;
});

console.log(x)
```

**OR:** With simple *for* loop

```js
var x = [2, -1, 4, -3]
for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
  if(x[i] < 0) 
    x[i] = 0;
}
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Avoid using `for..in` to loop an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea). Alternatively you can use any other array methods.

For example here [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is used or you can use normal `for` loop. In this snippet it is checking if each element is greater than 0 , else replacing that element with 0

```js
var x = [2, -1, 4, -3]

x.forEach(function(item, index) {
  if (item < 0) {
    x[index] = 0
  }
})

console.log(x)
```